# The Odin Project // Git push heroku master

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am a total newbie in all of this, so forgive my ignorance.

Recently bumped into The Odin Project & wanted to learn how to code.
Got busy with downloading all the necessary programs [Installfest] , when this occurred:

http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/deploy_a_rails_app

On **Step 2.5**: Deploy (push) to heroku, they ask me to do the following:

---

Type this in terminal --> `git push heroku master`

**Expected result:**

```
The authenticity of host 'heroku.com (75.101.145.87)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 8b:48:5e:67:0e:c9:16:47:32:f2:87:0c:1f:c8:60:ad.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'heroku.com,75.101.145.87' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Counting objects: 60, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (54/54), done.
Writing objects: 100% (60/60), 79.03 KiB, done.
Total 60 (delta 10), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Rails app detected
   Compiled slug size is 080K
-----> Launching...... done
   App deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:floating-winter-18.git
  * [new branch]      master -> master
```

---

When running this command in the command prompt With Ruby & Rails, I get the following message/issue/error:

**Actual result:**

> Username for 'https://git.heroku.com':

---

This is totally not what should be showing up, and I don't really know anything about how to solve this problem. Does any of you guys know how I can solve this so I can continue installing the programs necessary to start coding?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `heroku` account to push it to heroku. If you don't have one you can one [here](https://signup.heroku.com/)

Once you have a `heroku` account. All you need to do is to type this in terminal:

`heroku login`

Enter your Heroku credentials and you shall be able to push code to your website.

Comment: Also he might need to install the heroku toolbelt for further things to be done

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're going to need to ensure you have your Heroku Toolbelt installed. If you haven't installed it, you can check it out here: https://toolbelt.heroku.com/.

Secondly, visit https://www.heroku.com/ and sign up for an account.

Once you've successfully registered, you can run `heroku login` from your terminal and enter the credentials you just used for your account creation.

Lastly, re-run your `git push heroku master` command and enjoy your successful push!